# Python - Extract a regex match AND substitute it in one go?

Tags: python, regex, substitution, text-extraction

I want to remove leading white space from a string but also extract it. I went with:

```
m = re.search( r"^(\s*)", text )
leading_space = m.group(1)
text = re.sub( r"^\s*", "", text )
```

Surely there must be a more elegant solution?

In perl I would write:

```
$text =~ s/^(\s+)//;
$leading_space = $1;
```

Which is a lot more concise and runs the regex only once.

Also, the python code will fail if the regex isn't written in a way that guarantees it will always match (for instance by replacing the `*` with a `+`) leading to ugly code like:

```
if m:
  leading_space = m.group(1)
else:
  leading_space = ""
```

I find that I'm often writing ugly code in python because I don't know the clever shortcuts. I'm keen to learn to write more elegant python if you can help me.

Here's a fully functioning test script:

```
text = """
 Some text
maybe with multiple lines
"""

print( f"Working with <<{text}>>" )

m = re.search( r"^(\s*)", text )
leading_space = m.group(1)
text = re.sub( r"^\s*", "", text )

print( f"Got leading space: <<{leading_space}>>" )
print( f"and text         : <<{text}>>" )
```

And the one in perl:

```
my $text = "
 Some text
maybe with multiple lines
";

print( "Working with <<$text>>\n" );

$text =~ s/^(\s+)//;
$leading_space = $1;

print( "Got leading space: <<$leading_space>>\n" );
print( "and text         : <<$text>>\n" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use unpacking:

```py
import re

text = '   fooo  '

space, text = re.search(r'^(\s*)(.*)', text, flags = re.S).groups()
# ...or       re.search(r'^(\s*)([\s\S]*)', text)

print(space, text)  # '   ', 'fooo  '
```

Comment: You need to use the `re.DOTALL` flag, OP is using text with linebreaks.

Comment: Would adding (?s) in the regex  also work?

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).